# PHP Replace all Matching Tags & Escape Not Matching Text

Tags: php, regex

I have some `HTML` coming from users which may contain some tags. I want to do 2 things, first get all of my required tags & replace them with new tags and second escape other remaining text of user.

For example, consider this is HTML coming from my users which has some of my required tags

```
Hello! This is John. I have attached image <img class="someImg" unic="img.jpg">. And Visit this URL example.com
Yes! some injection like <script>alert('Hello');</script>
```

I want to get complete `<img>` tag with attributes within it and replace it with my own Tag. Also get any URL it contains. Rest all of the text should be escaped and sanitized.

I found a function `preg_replace_callback_array` this does good job as it searches regex for img and url and replace but only problem is that it does not nothing for those which are not matched by any regex.

```
$patterns = [
   "/(http(s)?:\/\/)?([a-z]*\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/" => functionforFoundURL,
   "/<img [^>]*class=\"[^\"]*\someImg\b[^\"]*\"[^>]* unic=\"(.*?)\"[^>]*>/" => 'functionforFoundImg',
];
preg_replace_callback_array($patterns, $html)
```

It runs my functions for replacing matching regex of Img & URL but nothing for remaining text which should be escaped.

If I escape result of `preg_replace_callback_array` with `htmlspecialchars` after I have replaced tags with my new tags then it will escape whole string.

Comment: you can: 1 - replace img tags with placeholder. 2 - escape rest of the string e regex img tags. 3 - concat strings

Comment: @GiacomoM Thank you for your kind suggestion but I could not get it clearly. Can you show some code example please

Answer (score 1):

There is an answer that recommended not to use regular expression with HTML in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).
I'm not sure and didn't know much about this.
So, I'll use PHP [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) instead because it is easier.

##### Code

```
$string = 'Hello! This is John. I have attached image <img class="someImg" unic="img.jpg">. And Visit this URL example.com
Image with on events. <img class="someImg" unic="img.jpg" onclick="alert(\'no!\');" onload="console.log(\'img load\');">
Yes! some injection like <script>alert(\'Hello\');</script>. And child item like <div>div<p>paragraph</p></div>
<p>The end</p>';

$Dom = new \DOMDocument();
// load HTML with custom `<body>` to prevent it auto wrap with `<p>`. Or in the end you can change from remove `<body>` to `<p>` if you don't use this.
$Dom->loadHTML('<body>' . $string . '</body>', LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED|LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$foundUrls = [];
grabUrlsAndSanitize($Dom, $foundUrls);

// get the result and remove custom `<body>`, `</body>`.
$output = str_replace(['<body>', '</body>'], '', $Dom->saveHTML());

echo '<strong>output:</strong> ' . htmlspecialchars($output, ENT_QUOTES);
echo '<br>' . PHP_EOL;
echo '<strong>found URLs:</strong> <pre>' . print_r($foundUrls, true) . '</pre>';


/**
 * Grab URLs and sanitize scripting such as script or events.
 *
 * @param DOMNode $DomNode
 * @param array $foundUrls
 * @return void
 */
function grabUrlsAndSanitize(DOMNode $DomNode, &$foundUrls)
{
    // sanitize all <script> tags.
    foreach ($DomNode->getElementsByTagName('script') as $script) {
        $script->parentNode->removeChild($script);
    }

    foreach ($DomNode->childNodes as $Node) {
        if ($Node->nodeType === XML_ELEMENT_NODE) {
            if ($Node->hasAttributes()) {
                // if element contains attributes.
                for ($i = $Node->attributes->length - 1; $i >= 0; --$i) {
                    $attribute = $Node->attributes->item($i);
                    if (is_object($attribute) && property_exists($attribute, 'name')) {
                        // sanitize on event such as onload onclick etc.
                        if (preg_match('/on([a-z]+)/iu', $attribute->name)) {
                            $Node->removeAttributeNode($Node->attributes->item($i));
                        }

                        // grab url from `unic` attribute.
                        if (strtolower($attribute->name) === 'unic') {
                            // if found unic="..."
                            $foundUrls[] = $attribute->value;
                        }
                    }
                    unset($attribute);
                }
            }

            if ($Node->hasChildNodes()) {
                grabUrlsAndSanitize($Node, $foundUrls);
            }
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

##### Result:

```
output: Hello! This is John. I have attached image <img class="someImg" unic="img.jpg">. And Visit this URL example.com
Image with on events. <img class="someImg" unic="img.jpg">
Yes! some injection like . And child item like <div>div<p>paragraph</p></div>
<p>The end</p>

found URLs:

Array
(
    [0] => img.jpg
    [1] => img.jpg
)
```

#### Security note

It is not 100% safe to use the function above to sanitize scripting to prevent XSS. There are a lot more things to do with this. Please read more about this at [OWASP](https://owasp.org/www-project-web-security-testing-guide/latest/4-Web_Application_Security_Testing/07-Input_Validation_Testing/01-Testing_for_Reflected_Cross_Site_Scripting), [XSS Filter Evasion Cheat Sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet.html).

For better XSS prevention, I recommend use [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/), [HTML-Sanitizer](https://github.com/tgalopin/html-sanitizer) or looking for something else similar.